# What is this common depiction of Ali ibn Abi Talib (ra), Hasan ibn Ali and Husayn ibn Ali in Shia islam based on?

Tags: shirk, shiism, ali, hussain

[image]

Are their facial features, clothes etc. modelled after certain hadiths, if so which one?

Also when did this start and how ISN'T this idolatry?

Is it possible even that those aren't actual paintings dreamed up by an artist at some point but rather "paintings" traced after photographs of real people? (I've seen some photographs online, that looked eerily alike!)

Answer (score 1):

These images were drawn by artists based on mental images and definitions that came from the faces of imams, and they do not have a document that shows that these images are authentic.
In the general public, sometimes it seems that a person is honoring the photo itself, which is prohibited by Shia scholars.
In the Shia view, imams have respect and status because the Prophet of Islam introduced them as his successors in the [Ghadir sermon](https://en.wikishia.net/view/Al-Ghadir_Sermon) and several other cases.

Comment: Interesting. When we're talking about exactly these faces shown above (it's always the exact same faces somehow), what's the first instance of them appearing somewhere? I've noticed Husayn is often depicted with feathers on his helmet, do they hold any significant meaning?

Comment: Dear @islam22!They would install these feathers on their helmets to distinguish this person from others on the battlefield. The presence of famous warriors in the battle encouraged the companions and apprehensiveness of the other side (it was customary at that time), but the reason why Imam Hussain (AS) is usually shown with his helmet in the pictures is that, from the 12 Shia Imams, only Imam Hossein was martyred in the battlefield and 10 other imams were also martyred by biological assassination.